# Hardware does not support the number of textures defined (Using VTK/PCL)

Tags: opengl, graphics, vtk, point-cloud-library, meshlab

I am trying to view textures in Point Cloud Library (PCL). I have a texture data file (.obj) and corresponding wavefront meterial file (.mtl) along with 5 images.

When I load this data in Meshlab, the texture is mapped but when I load it in pcl using following code;

```
pcl::TextureMesh mesh7;
pcl::io::loadOBJFile("textured_mesh.obj", mesh7);
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer_pre7("PCL Viewer_pre7");
viewer_pre7.addTextureMesh(mesh7, "texture", 0);
viewer_pre7.spin();
```

I get following error in vtkOutputWindow. Although I can see the mesh structure but the texture is not mapped.

ERROR: In ..\vtkOpenGLProperty.cxx, line 607
vtkOpenGLProperty (000002420C804BA0): Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.

Mesh without texture in PCL

[image: Mesh without texture in PCL]

Same file when loaded in Meshgrid

[image: Same file when loaded in Meshgrid]

Where shall I look for solving this error? Is PCL good enough for loading and viewing textures (.obj, .mtl)?